# Binding Not Updating Even Though Property Is

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am working on a user control which has dozens of binding (some through `DependencyProperties` and other's through properties using `INotifyPropertyChanged`) and all of them are working completely fine except for a single one.

In the XAML I have:

```xml
<TextBox Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding FilterPreview, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

and the property itself is:

```cs
private string FilterPreview
{
    get { return filterPreview; }
    set
    {
        filterPreview = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilterPreview));
    }
}
```

But it doesn't matter what I set `FilterPreview` to, the text box **never shows any value**.  I even added a button that would just set `FilterPreview` to the current time to test.  When I add a breakpoint, I can see that `FilterPreview` itself is being updated correctly, but I cannot figure out why the value is not showing in the textbox.

Just as an example, about 10 lines up in the XAML I have this line:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ShowAdvancedFilterBuilderButtonText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

with the property:

```cs
public string ShowAdvancedFilterBuilderButtonText
{
    get { return showAdvancedFilterBuilderButtonText; }
    set
    {
        showAdvancedFilterBuilderButtonText = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShowAdvancedFilterBuilderButtonText));
    }
}
```

and that one works fine even though they are basically exactly the same.  I should also mention that I tried using `TwoWay` for the `Mode` property in the XAML and the property didn't get updated with the value.  I also tried removing the `RelativeSource` and `UpdateSourceTrigger` properties but that didn't help anything either.

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need a `Two-Way` binding?

Comment: This is not something the user is able to update.  It should update with a preview of information for a filter being built.  That is why it was a TextBlock and not a TextBox.  But I even tried using TwoWay for the Mode property and it still didn't help.

Comment: And plus that second example doesn't have two-way binding, or any other properties set, and it works exactly as expected.  I can't figure out why this new one isn't working exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only bind to `public` properties, not `private` ones. The property in your second example is `public` and that is why it works. Change the `FilterPreview` property access modifier accordingly.

```
public string FilterPreview
{
   get { return filterPreview; }
   set
   {
      filterPreview = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilterPreview));
   }
}
```

Comment: Holy hell!  I've been working on this for close to 45 minutes trying to figure out what it was and I knew it was going to be some stupid mistake I missed!  Thank you.  I knew having a second set of eyes would help.